# Where can I find a set of Java test programs with injected errors?

Tags: java

I need some fairly simple Java test programs with injected errors in order to test something I'm working on on them.

Edit: By "injected errors" I mean broken algorithms, errors that may cause the program to crash, and so on...

Edit2: I'm making something that tries to give some hints to the programmer about the cause of the error, so the programs should be fairly simple and contain known errors in them.

Comment: You need to be more specific - inject errors into what? What are you trying to test?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like [WebGoat](http://code.google.com/p/webgoat/)? It is a java web app with security errors.

I'm not sure if those are the "injected errors" you are looking for.

Comment: Not exactly what I had in mind, but it may be useful, I'm going to have to look into it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I've broken a few of J2EE and Swing sample programs for [a study that I did](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~udekel/papers/udekel_emoose_icse2009.pdf), I can share the sources if you need.